# BERT for classification model degenerates into all-positive predictions

Tags: nlp, training, bert, huggingface

As a learning project, I'm training a BERT model with the CoLA dataset to detect sentence acceptability. Unfortunately my model is learning to classify every instance as "acceptable", and I'm not sure what is going wrong with my code. Can anyone provide any help or insight into why this happens?

#### Technical details

I'm using hugging face's `transformers` library with PyTorch.

The (stripped version of the) code is as follows. Instrumentation and other details have been left out so the code is more readable.

```py
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

model = transformers.AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    'bert-base-cased',
    num_labels=2,
)

optimizer = transformers.AdamW(
    model.parameters(),
    lr=2e-5,
    eps=1e-8,
)

# The next lines read the CoLA dataset and split it for training and validation
training_dataloader = ...
validation_dataloader = ...

for epoch in range(4):
    train_loss = 0

    for batch in tqdm(train_dataloader):
        model.train()

        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        labels = batch['label'].to(device)

        model.zero_grad()

        model_output = model(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            labels=labels,
            return_dict=True,
        )

        batch_loss = model_output.loss.sum()

        train_loss += batch_loss.item()

        batch_loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        optimizer.step()

        # HERE: Measure performance after learning from each batch here with validation_dataloader
```

I've checked and the code that reads the dataset seems correct, so it seems that the problem lies either in measuring the performance of the model or in the learning phase.

To measure the performance, I'm running the model over the validation split and then converting the logits into actual classifications as follows:

```py
tp = fn = fp = tn = 0

for batch in validation_dataloader:
    input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
    attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
    labels = batch['label'].to(device)

    model(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        attention_mask=attention_mask,
        labels=labels,
        return_dict=True,
    )

    expected = batch['label']
    predictions = output.logits[:,1] > output.logits[:,0] # Is this correct?

    tp += sum(1 for exp, pred in zip(expected, predictions) if     exp and     pred)
    fn += sum(1 for exp, pred in zip(expected, predictions) if     exp and not pred)
    fp += sum(1 for exp, pred in zip(expected, predictions) if not exp and     pred)
    tn += sum(1 for exp, pred in zip(expected, predictions) if not exp and not pred)
```

Is the line `predictions = ...` correct?

Comment: is the dataset balanced?

Comment: It's 70/30, so not really unbalanced. I've also tried to undersample my dataset to ensure 50/50 distribution of labels but the problem persists.

Comment: I've added a bit more on how I'm measuring validation, since it may also be the point of failure.

Comment: `predictions = torch.argmax(output.logits,dim=1)` should do the job

Comment: That may be a better way to express the computation, but computes the exact same thing, I think...

Comment: I still don't know what's wrong with my code, but I changed it to use huggingface's Trainer class and now the model is learning to predict positive labels an expected amount of times, with a matthews correlation coefficient of about 0.47.